# Breakpoint not being hit while debugging WCF application

Tags: .net, wcf

I have a WCF application and a console application.

I published WCF application in a separate folder. Added a Virtual Application in IIS.

In console application, I added a Service Reference to the site added in IIS.

With this, I am unable to debug WCF application and the breakpoint is not hitting.

I opened two instances of VS. In once instance, I executed WCF application and in the other, the console application.

Why the WCF breakpoints not hitting?

Comment: Why did you publish the WCF application to IIS? For me it is not clear why you are having this step at least for the development. It is enough to start the WCF application through VS. Then use this address for your console client application.

Comment: @Marc Which address ? The localhost address the WCF application shows in browser? The same has to be added as Service Reference ?

Comment: @Marc The WCF application, opens with the address: http://localhost:52099/. I tried to add this as the Service Reference in console application, but the reference is not found.

Comment: Yes, the same address needs to be used. Otherwise it is not the service you can/want to debug with VS. I will post an answer for this. With and without using service references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to publish the WCF application manually to an IIS for development/debugging purposes. The hosting part is already built-in into Visual Studio.

If you want to connect a client application to a WCF Service, there are two ways I can think of:

**Method 1: Use a Service Reference**

That is the quickest approach and works in most cases out of the box (You have chosen this one).

You need to have a solution file with client and server projects similar to this one:

[image]

In the "Add Service Reference" Dialog, click "Discover". This will look for WCF services in your solution (this services don't need to be started).

Side note: If you click on "Go", only a started service can be found.

[image]

You should see your service in the "Services" section and the Address Field is automatically filled out for you with the address Visual Studio will use for local debugging.

[image]

Continue adding the service as you always do...

Visual Studio will automatically update the client's app.config file.

If you start the console application only, Visual Studio will also start the service in background for you. You are able to step into the service operation by hitting F11 without explicit setting a breakpoint.

**Method 2: Without using service references**

Clicking on "Add service Reference" will generate code based on the current data contracts. If you change that definition (types, operations, etc.), you have to generate it again.

If you are the owner of both, client and service, then you can create a dynamic proxy at runtime using WCF Channelfactory.

You have to extract the Service contract and Data contracts only to a new assembly and share it with client and server.
There is no code generation necessary and this way you will always be safe at compile time. 
See [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/138388/Dynamic-Generation-of-Client-Proxy-at-Runtime-in) for more information.

Because VS is not aware of any service references, you have to start both projects by yourself. Just set multiple startup projects in your solution and press F5.
But in this case, you have to set a breakpoint in your service application.

Comment: I tried the first approach. Added WCF to the same solution and added service reference. 

I am getting error: Method 'GetOrders' in type 'SMService.ServiceImplementation.SMTransactionService' from assembly 'SMService.ServiceImplementation, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.

I am unable to find the Interface in all the projects which does not have an implementation.